# verbose_name for ManyToManyField not displayed

Tags: django, admin

the verbose_name I set for a ManyToManyField is not displayed in my admin. Is that because I override the form? Anybody can help?

Thanks!

**models.py**

```
class PC(models.Model):
    #...
    mag_blacklist = models.ManyToManyField(Magasin, verbose_name="test")
```

**admin.py**

```
class PCForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mag_blacklist = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Magasin.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I am pretty much sure thats why! just change the label in your form field then:

```
mag_blacklist = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Magasin.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label="test")
```

Or you can get the actual verbose like this:

```
mag_blacklist = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Magasin.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label=Magasin._meta.get_field_by_name('mag_blacklist')[0].verbose_name)
```

try it out! lemme know if works