# verbose_name for ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm new in django .I need a verbose_name for my ManyToManyField so I used this :

```
#encoding:UTF-8
name = models.ManyToManyField(Name, verbose_name = "طبقه")
```

but in admin interface I see this:
[image: first]

when I use english name It works fine and I see this!

```
name = models.ManyToManyField(Name, verbose_name = "Test")
```

[image: second]

what should I do?

Comment: You need to internationalize https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/i18n/

Comment: Tnx . But what's wrong with my  code ?

Comment: The default lang must have been set to eng, so its able to display only english values

Comment: this method works fine with other field !! but in manytomany field It doesn't work

Comment: Do you override your model as a form in admin.py?

Comment: yes but az you can see in the picture It dosen't work

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931176/verbose-name-for-manytomanyfield-not-displayed